# In MVC, After new Master Record, redirect to view for secondary file with many records to tie to master

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I'm an MVC Newbie. I realize this is very basic stuff.

During entry of a Master Record, how do I get my MVC Controler action to redirect to a View for a secondary file that holds multiple records linked to the master record.

The scaffolding provides a view and controller to enter the master record but then takes you back to the Index View. I have tried various things in the controller to do this, but I'm striking out.

The tables are very simple and hold people and charges. One person, many charges.

I need to...

1. Enter new person record
2. Click Save
3. Navigate to view that allows entry of one or many charges that will be linked to the person.

Here is my Post in the controller.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(dataOffender offender)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.dataOffenders.Add(offender);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

            <<<<<<<<<TODO:redirect to my charges "CreateCharge" view.                             

        }

        return View(offender);
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to the Index after saving the new entry, instead you should redirect to the action CreateCharge.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(dataOffender offender)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     db.dataOffenders.Add(offender);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("CreateCharge", new KeyValuePair(offender.Key, offender.Value));
   }
   return View(offender);
}

public ActionResult CreateCharge(KeyValuePair kvp)
{
   ViewBag.OffenderKeyValue = kvp;
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Hi Shiffty,  thanks for looking at this.  What I'm stuck on is when I go to the Create Charge, I have a key value in the Master record that needs to be consistent with any charges I add in the CreateCharge view.

Comment: Hi David. You want to pass some dependencies from the master record to the charges right? I've update my answer according to that, I hope this is what you need.